# Spring roo - how to install spring surf

Tags: java, spring-roo, spring-surf

could please anybody help me to install spring surf ?

According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdfNbfdoIaU&feature=player_detailpage#t=88s), there should be command "roo>install surf" or roo>addon install surf"  but the install command doesn't exist

If I go "addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName" and let the content assist list the add-ons available, it is not there

Also [this site](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Surf_Developer_Tools) says to download org.springframework.roo.addon.alfresco.surf-1.0.0.RC3.jar  and put it into $ROO_HOME/dist directory (which is btw not there). I created dist dir, restarted roo, but nothing happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addon install doesn't works anymore for the latest versions of spring roo

You should try with osgi

i.e.

```
osgi install --url file:/c://test/spring-surf-roo-addon-1.0.0-RC2.jar
```

use the right url to the .jar file

Answer (score 0):

The command from the installation instructions for the [1.0.0-RC2](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0-RC2/spring-surf-devtools/spring-surf-roo-addon/reference/html/intro.html#intro-installation) is:

```
addon install --url http://www.springsurf.org/downloads/1.0.0-RC2/spring-surf-roo-addon-1.0.0-RC2-roo-addon.zip
```

Comment: Thanks Serhii, but --url attribute doesn't exist in my version of roo "1.1.2.RELEASE [rev fbc33bb]"

Comment: I see, I overlooked that it is for 1.0.0-RC2 ... well so far it seems that spring roo needs at least half a year before I give it a try, I got like 5 different kinds of errors that I couldn't do anything about ... then this thingy...uff

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked before answering. It seems that the surf addon only works with ROO 1.0.X.

Comment: Please use the latest version of Roo whenever possible, as there are bugs which were related to addon installation which were fixed in the most recent versions.