# Spring surf and webscripts projects disambiguation

Tags: java, spring-roo, alfresco, spring-surf

I recently came across [spring surf project](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-surf) and [Spring webscripts](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M3/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts-documentation/reference/index.html) .

Both these technologies (I guess) seem to come from Alfresco developers

[Web Scripts](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts)

[Surf](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Surf_Platform_-_Developers_Guide)

Is it correct ?

As I was investigating both of them couple of hours, it seems to be very clever technology. Little bit focused on CMS, but it makes better impression and sense than JSPs, Icefaces (which I haven't liked for many years, but I've been forced to use them).

It's a shame that both technologies are in state of incubation within springsource.

Could please anybody who has experience with them tell us some stories from production use ?

I noticed that Surf can be used together with Spring Roo. Is there any other support, like maven, IDE etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those technologies were developed by Alfresco and then donated to Springsource to detach them from Alfresco and become first-class web development libraries.

I'm not aware of any remarkable use of those libraries out of the Alfresco scope, but that's most likely because of my current focus being on Alfresco, or because they are still quite new as standalone projects.

Have a look at [Alfresco Share](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Share) or the [Web QuickStart](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Installation_and_Configuration) to see how web scripts and Surf are used to create fully functional and standalone applications.

Spring Surf and web scripts are built with maven and deployed into [Alfresco maven](http://nexus.alfresco.com/nexus/index.html#welcome) repository, which should give you enough support for your maven builds. I'm not aware of any maven archetype for Surf or web scripts.

As per developer tools, I'm only aware of Spring Roo. The [official documentation](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M2/spring-surf-devtools/spring-surf-roo-addon/reference/html/beginning.html) could bring some more information, though.

Comment: thanks for clarification, it looks that surf can be used only with Roo 1.0.0 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5137896/306488 which is a version you wouldn't want to work with :-)